# GIMP: Set All New Images to Default Transparent Background?

Tags: gimp, transparency

Is there a way in GIMP to set an option so that all new images are created with a transparent background?

Currently, when I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>  (New Image), I have to click "Advanced Options", then open the dialogue "Fill" box and select "Transparent". A real timewaster.

Any help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To change the Default for new images open up *GIMP* and go to *Edit → Preferences*. Select *Default Image* and change *Fill with:* to *Transparency*.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: I can't thank you enough.  If I had SuperUser gold, I would give you some!